# Find all invariant lines of an affine transformation in plane

Tags: linear-transformations, affine-geometry

Suppose we have affine transformation:

$$\begin{align}x^* &= 2x+y-2\\
y^* &= -3x- y\end{align}$$

How can we find the equations of all invariant lines?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a line originally is $y=ax+b$. After transformation is $y^*=a^*x^*+b^*$. Plug in your equations for $x^*$ and $y^*$ into this equation, group the terms so you can rewrite it as $$y=f(a^*,b^*)x+g(a^*,b^*)$$
Since the line is invariant, you have the same coefficients so $$f(a,b)=a\\g(a,b)=b$$

Comment: You’re omitting vertical lines ($x=k$).

Comment: Yes. I should have mentioned that you need to check that. It is trivial to show that it is not invariant

Comment: In this case, yes, but you’re presenting $y=ax+b$ as the generic equation of any line whatsoever.

Comment: I could have done $ax+by+c=0$, but then I need to check the ratio of the coefficients, since $2ax+2by+2c=0$ is the same line.

Comment: Either way you have to make an extra check beyond what you’ve got here: on the one hand you have to deal separately with vertical lines, on the other you have to examine ratios.

Comment: You are right. Dealing separately looks easier.

Answer (score 0):

Calling $p = (x,y),\, b = (-2,0)$ we have the generic line as

$$
p = p_0 + \lambda \vec v
$$

then

$$
 p_0 + \lambda \vec v = A( p_0+\lambda\vec v) + b
$$

or

$$
A p_0-p_0+b = \lambda(\vec v-A\vec v),\,\,\forall \lambda\in \mathbb{R}
$$

so we have

$$
(A-I_2)\vec v  = 0\\
(A-I_2)p_0 + b = 0
$$

now solving for $\vec v, p_0$ we have the invariant lines.

Answer (score 0):

Working in homogeneous coordinates, the point transformation $\mathbf x'=M\mathbf x$ transforms lines as $\mathbf l'=M^{-T}\mathbf l$. The invariant lines $\mathbf l=(\lambda,\mu,\tau)^T$ are those for which $M^{-T}\mathbf l$ is a nonzero multiple of $\mathbf l$, so finding them amounts to finding eigenvectors of $M^{-T}$ that correspond to real nonzero eigenvalues. Alternatively, since the homogeneous coordinates are three-dimensional, the invariant lines are the solutions of $\mathbf l\times M^{-T}\mathbf l=0$.

Note that the line at infinity is always an invariant line of an affine transformation: the last column of $M^{-T}$ for such a transformation is $(0,0,1)^T$.